# Putting Channel Create statement in IF statement breaks code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have some code to create a new channel off a post request. Everything works fine, except when I put the creation into an if-statement to check if a ticket already exists. This is my code

```
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('858917141063401512');
const user = await client.users.cache.get(content.id);
const prefix = 't!';
if (client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `ticket-${content.id}`)) {
    user.send('you already have a ticket, please close your exsisting ticket first before opening a new one!');
    created = true;
} else {
    created = false;
    guild.channels.create(`ticket-${content.id}`, {
        permissionOverwrites: [
            {
            id: content.id,
            allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        {
            id: '858917141063401512', //change to everyone ID in server
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        ],
        type: 'text',
    }).then(async channel => {
        user.send(`you have successfully created a ticket! Please click on ${channel} to view your ticket.`);
        user.send(`Hi ${content.id}, welcome to your ticket! Please be patient, we will be with you shortly. If you would like to close this ticket please run \`${prefix}close\``);
        let logchannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `ticket-logs`);
        if (logchannel) {
            logchannel.send(`Ticket ${content.id} created. Click the following to view <#${channel.id}>`);
        }
    });
    }
```

The error i recieve is

```
(node:1793) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.
```

For the line

```
guild.channels.create(`ticket-${content.id}`, {
```

Comment: Have you defined user? If so, please add that into your code.

Comment: Yes they are defined before,         const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('858917141063401512');
        const user = await client.users.cache.get(content.id);
        const prefix = 't!';

Comment: Could you add it into the code in the question? That way we (anyone trying to answer your question) can gain a better understanding and actually be able to read it.

Comment: @Tyler2P I did, its at the top

Comment: It says i need 2k rep to use the edit suggestion for whoever did that

Comment: You can edit your own posts with 1 reputation

Comment: What is `content`? Also, can you `console.log(user.id);` after you declare `user` and see what it says?

Comment: @PerplexingParadox i was able to fix it, i just had to wait for the bot to login lol